# C# Сохранение списка объектов класса, в котором есть структура, в JSON

Tags: c#, json, сериализация

Есть класс с различными полями, в том числе и полем struct

```
 [Serializable]
    public class example
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ...
        public struct test_struct

        {
            public string var1;
            public string var2;
            public string var3;
        }
        public static List<example> collection = new List<example>();

        public example()
        {
            collection.Add(this);
        }
```

Имеется список объектов этого класса, которые записаны в example.collections

Например,

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    example new_collection = new();
    example.test_struct new_struct = new();
    example.Name = "king";
    new_struct.var1 = "mask";
    new_struct.var2 = "client";
    new_struct.var3 = "sun";

}
```

Вопрос: Как сохранить объекты класса вместе со структурой в Json? Я пробую сохранить список объектов, но структура при этом не сохраняется (почему?):

```
public void SaveToJson<T>(List<T> list, string filename)
    {
        string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(list);
        File.WriteAllText(filename, json);
    }

...

SaveToJson(example.collection, "filename.json");
```

Если вместо структуры сделать массив, то он прекрасно сохраняется.

Comment: Сделайте свойство в классе с вашей структурой, туда и сохраняйте. Ну и в структуре поля на свойства поменяйте

Comment: Точно, я понял, что ты имеешь ввиду, большое спасибо за совет. Я попробую

Comment: Тут такая засада случилась, я сделал, как Вы посоветовали. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой.
При обращении к структуре, возвращается полная структура из списка, то есть я не смог обратиться отдельно к полям в структуре.
```
public test_struct struct1 { get; set; }
...
example.struct1.var1 = value;
```
CS1612 Не удалось изменить возвращаемое значение, т.к оно не является переменной.

Могу ли я обращаться к элементам структуры, и перезаписывать их каким либо образом?

Comment: Сама концепция `struct` подразумевает что она [является значением и неизменяемо](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct). Я бы посоветовал копаться в сторону реализации `JsonConverter`, где собственно можно указать в каком виде записывать и считывать `struct`.

Comment: У меня получилось. В общем, я сделал так:

1) Сделал свойство в классе с моей структурой.
2) Создал копию структуры, заполнил копию значениями.
3) Скопировал содержимое копии структуры в свойство класса со структурой.
Это нужно для того, чтобы я не редактировал отдельно поля, а скопировал всё разом.

Я даже не знаю, правильно ли я объяснил, и поймет ли кто-то, что я написал)